# Showing value inside bubble of folium

Tags: python, folium

I am trying to show the values battery storage capacity of some countries in Maps: I want to show it through bubble maps on folium charts according to the size

My code is as following.

```
import folium

# Make an empty map
m = folium.Map(location=[20,0], tiles="OpenStreetMap", zoom_start=2)

# Import the pandas library
import pandas as pd

# Make a data frame with dots to show on the map
data = pd.DataFrame({
   'lon':[-58, 2, 145, 30.32, -4.03, -73.57, 36.82, -38.5],
   'lat':[-34, 49, -38, 59.93, 5.33, 45.52, -1.29, -12.97],
   'name':['Buenos Aires', 'Paris', 'melbourne', 'St Petersbourg', 'Abidjan', 'Montreal', 'Nairobi', 'Salvador'],
   'value':[10, 12, 40, 70, 23, 43, 100, 43]
}, dtype=str)

for i in range(0,len(data)):
   folium.Circle(
      location=[data.iloc[i]['lat'], data.iloc[i]['lon']],
      popup=data.iloc[i]['name'],
      radius=float(data.iloc[i]['value'])*20000,
      color='crimson',
      fill=True,
      fill_color='crimson'
   ).add_to(m)

m.save('bubble_folium.html')
```

The output is somewhat like this.

[image: Output image]

I want add the numbers inside the box, please guide me.

I just need a static image any solution using seaborn library to reach my goal is also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Marker` to add text, then adjust the `icon_size` and `icon_anchor` as you wish. Refer to [doc of folium](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html#Markers).

```
import folium
from folium.features import DivIcon

# Make an empty map
m = folium.Map(location=[20,0], tiles="OpenStreetMap", zoom_start=2)

# Import the pandas library
import pandas as pd

# Make a data frame with dots to show on the map
data = pd.DataFrame({
   'lon':[-58, 2, 145, 30.32, -4.03, -73.57, 36.82, -38.5],
   'lat':[-34, 49, -38, 59.93, 5.33, 45.52, -1.29, -12.97],
   'name':['Buenos Aires', 'Paris', 'melbourne', 'St Petersbourg', 'Abidjan', 'Montreal', 'Nairobi', 'Salvador'],
   'value':[10, 12, 40, 70, 23, 43, 100, 43]
}, dtype=str)

for i in range(0,len(data)):
   folium.Circle(
      location=[data.iloc[i]['lat'], data.iloc[i]['lon']],
      popup=data.iloc[i]['name'],
      radius=float(data.iloc[i]['value'])*20000,
      color='crimson',
      fill=True,
      fill_color='crimson'
   ).add_to(m)
   
   folium.map.Marker([data.iloc[i]['lat'], data.iloc[i]['lon']],
                      icon=DivIcon(
                          icon_size=(10 ,10),
                          icon_anchor=(15,15),
                          html=f'<div style="font-size: 14pt">%s</div>' % data.iloc[i]['value'],
                      )
                     ).add_to(m)
   

m.save('bubble_folium.html')
```

Output :

[image]